# TextToSpeech not working

Tags: android

There is no sound output in my project-- onInit code above attached. I am unable to resolve it despite several attempts. Friends, please help!
     // import all the needed stuff
     import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.util.Locale; 
        //for this project I am changing the Api level to 21 from 15
        @TargetApi(21)

```
    public class TextToSpeechActivity extends AppCompatActivity
           implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
       private EditText et;
       private TextToSpeech tts;
       private Button buttonspeak;
       private Button b2;
       private int result = 0;
       // onCreate method
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           // get all the view objects
           et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
           buttonspeak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonspeak);
           tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
           // set the listener on the button
           buttonspeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(View arg0){
                  // Log.e("Hi","Are you OK?");
                  // this  is by way of a helper method
                   speakOut();
               }
           });
       }
       @Override
       public void onDestroy(){
          // closing down tts
           if (tts != null){
               tts.stop();
               tts.shutdown();}
               super.onDestroy();
           }
       @Override
       public void onInit(int status){
           if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
       // set the language to US English
               result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
           // in case the language setting is not done properly
               if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA||result == 
       TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED ){
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Language not 
    available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   buttonspeak.setEnabled(false);}
            // if everything is fine
               else {buttonspeak.setEnabled(true);}}
           else { Log.e("TTS", "Initialisation failed");}}

       private void speakOut(){
          // get the string typed into the editbox
           String text = et.getText().toString();
           if (result != tts.setLanguage(Locale.US)){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter the right
     words",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
           else{
               tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
               // Log.e("Hi","Are you OK?");
           }

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

> More [Reference1](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/)
>
> More [Reference2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm)

Comment: I did call speakOut(). Rest of my code is as under:

Comment: import----
@TargetApi(21)
public class ---
    protected void onCreate(---) {
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        buttonspeak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonspeak);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
        buttonspeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                              speakOut(); }}); }     
        --
    public void onDestroy(){
        if (tts != null){
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();}
            super.onDestroy();
        }

Comment: @Venugopal please update your question instance of comments

Comment: @Venugopal  Please post your complete code so that i can able to help you where did you made mistake

Comment: Thanks Gowtham for taking the time out to follow my question. My problem is when I paste the whole code the site says that it is too long. When I try to add the remaining code in comments, the formatting is gone! Any way out this? I am a beginner as you would have by now rightly guessed!

Comment: package com.example.android.memory;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Locale;
@TargetApi(21)
public class TextToSpeechActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

Comment: @Venugopal sry bro..,, i am ready to help you..but i need full code...i am not getting clearly from your comment..post your complete code in your question...let me know...

Comment: Hi Gowthaman, I have now edited the question showing  the full code. Also there are no error messages for my code. It simply refuses to do the job! My activity_main xml file is ok. BTW I tried the full code you had sent by way of answer and that too is not working.

Comment: @Venugopal make it target api 24,,as well check some other device

Comment: Thank you very much Gowthaman for your help--target api 24 solved the problem!